# Window phone - How to appear SlideView in specific page?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone

I'm create slide menu as Facebook,and I'm follow this https://slideview.codeplex.com/ . And I have xaml code as below :

```
<Application.RootVisual>
 <library:SlideApplicationFrame Title="Slide View">
    <library:SlideApplicationFrame.LeftContent>
           <pages:LeftView />
    </library:SlideApplicationFrame.LeftContent>
    <library:SlideApplicationFrame.RightContent>
           <pages:RightView />
    </library:SlideApplicationFrame.RightContent>
</library:SlideApplicationFrame>
```

My problem is : Slide menu will be apply all page,but I want slide is appear in specific page .

Answer (score 0):

You can implement that by either  [Control animation while navigating between panes inside a Windows Phone page](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Control_animation_while_navigating_between_panes_inside_a_Windows_Phone_page)  `or`  [Add side menus to an Windows Phone application (similar to the Facebook app)](http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.in/2013/08/add-lateral-menus-to-windows-phone.html)

Answer (score 0):

Write the following lines of code in the constructor of page in which you want to hide slide view.
`SlideView.Library.SlideApplicationFrame.SetHideHeader(App.RootFrame, false);
            App.RootFrame.IsSlideEnabled =false;
            App.RootFrame.ToggleHeaderVisibility(false);`